# Which class is responsible for creating an instance of the block?

Tags: magento-1.9

Which class is responsible for creating an instance of the block?
Please give the answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Mage_Core_Model_Layout" this class creating instance of class .

class Mage_Core_Model_Layout extends Varien_Simplexml_Config
{

```
public function generateBlocks($parent=null)
{
    if (empty($parent)) {
        $parent = $this->getNode();
    }
    foreach ($parent as $node) {
        $attributes = $node->attributes();
        if ((bool)$attributes->ignore) {
            continue;
        }
        switch ($node->getName()) {              
            case 'block':
                $this->_generateBlock($node, $parent);
                $this->generateBlocks($node);
                break;

            case 'reference':
                $this->generateBlocks($node);
                break;

            case 'action':
                $this->_generateAction($node, $parent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}